# styling parent element based on child element Using CSS

Tags: css

Need to style **id="Parent"** based on **id="child"**
Kindly check with code for more understanding.

I'm using uniform.js for form control

when we write

```html
<select id="child"  class="input-validation-error">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Procurement</option>
    <option value="2">Cost Synergy</option>
    <option value="3">Revenue Synergy</option>
    <option value="4">Procurement Enabled Cost Synergy</option>
</select>
```

It Generates below code

```html
<div id="parent" class="selector">
<span>Select</span>
<select id="child"  class="input-validation-error">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="1">Procurement</option>
<option value="2">Cost Synergy</option>
<option value="3">Revenue Synergy</option>
<option value="4">Procurement Enabled Cost Synergy</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Can you please help me
Thank you
:)

Comment: you want to change parent class css according to child?

Comment: Yes you right :) want to change styling of parent based on child.

Comment: There is no selector in CSS that allows you to style a parent based on whether an element contains a certain child. Can you do it a different way (add a different class to the parent)? Would you be open to a jquery solution?

Comment: yes we can do very well using Jquery. but i don't want to use jquery because there are many jscript are running in my project.

Comment: I wouldn't want to use jQuery/javascript for this either. Your only option is to add a specific class to the ones you want to style differently.

Comment: I have updated the above Question...Please go through.

Answer (score 0):

attach an onchange="function(this)" with the child. define the function(this) in your js script. there you can simply do getElementById("parent").style.xyz='xyz'.

GOOD LUCK!!